# Simple REST Node.js API server, get all entries without one attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I prepared a simple node.js REST API

I wish that my user can take a look on the all rooms but without hidden_id parametr

Right now if my user enter in the browser https://mydomain/api/conferenceRooms
he see all conferences room with all atributes

```
 0  
_id "5a54016c5038c071a3efcd53"
name    "IoT"
number  5
hidden_id 098
temperature 348
__v 0
create_date "2018-01-08T23:40:28.061Z"
1   
_id "5a5403f16e1daf7a7058da0f"
name    "IoT"
number  6
hidden_id 09832
temperature 348
__v 0
create_date "2018-01-08T23:51:13.440Z"
```

My conference Room schema looks:

```
// ConferenceRoom Schema
const conferenceRoomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    number:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    hidden_id:{
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    temperature:{
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

My get functions is:

```
app.get('/api/conferenceRooms', (req, res) => {
    ConferenceRoom.getConferenceRooms((err, conferenceRooms) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(conferenceRooms);
    });
});
```

Is it possible that I show my user all entries but without hidden_id attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `delete` operation while filtering the `conferenceRooms`.

```
res.json(conferenceRooms.filter(function(conferenceRoom) {
  delete conferenceRoom.hidden_id;
  return conferenceRoom;
}))
```

what happens here is: the `conferenceRooms` array of objects is iterated and all `hidden_id`s of the objects are removed.

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/4k5k5brt/

Cheers!

Comment: That's unfortunate. I've added a fiddle to my answer for your reference. See if that helps.